# Force LINQ to SQL getting data just one time

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I'm using linq to sql. And do something like:

```
IEnumerable<VarValues> parameters = GetDayParameters();

protected IEnumerable<VarValues> GetDayParameters()
{
    return "some linq query";
}
```

After that, i'm using LINQ to Objects for "parameters"-variable, in loop, and that queries start to connect to database.
Question is, can i force LINQ to SQL, get, all i want from database into parameters variable, and do not connect to database, anymore.

Comment: please improve the title of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign the result of your linq query to var object v and then return v.ToList()

Answer (score 3):

Normally LINQ to SQL is not bound to database once you have received data from database.

like if you see following blog of ScottGu

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

You can connect to database get values and then play with your object and pass the values back.

ExampleЖ

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()
```

then you can query your database like

```
var mytable = from a in db.MyTable
              where yournormal_where_statement
              select a;
```

I hope it will help